# Set $myVar as a variable with wildcard

Tags: powershell, azure

I have the below script which I had help with from here, one quick question how do you I set `$MyVar` as  variable, and a wildcard so partial name can be selected.

```
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName "MySubscription"
Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | Where-Object {$_.ResourceGroupName -like '$MyVar'} | ForEach-Object {
    $VMs = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroupName
    ForEach ($vm in $vms) {
        $tags2 = $VM.tags
        $tags2 += @{ShutdownSchedule_AllowStart="True"; ShutdownSchedule_AllowStop="True" }

        Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceName $vm.Name -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -ResourceType "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" -Tag $tags2 -Force -Verbose
    }
}
```

Not sure how to set it as a variable. Was thinking maybe `{$_.ResourceGroupName -like $('$MyVar')}`

Or do I need to set it as a parameter, as in a workflow, but not sure how to do that outside a workflow..

Comment: Use double quotes so the variable can be expanded, and add `*` to either end you want to wildcard `{$_.ResourceGroupName -like "*$MyVar*"}`

Comment: @JamesC. Thanks James, can I use $myvar = Read-Host "Enter Variable" ..Would that work and pass it through?

Comment: For the script you've used as an example, yes that would work. Using a script param would also be an option.

Comment: @JamesC. Perfect, Thanks James :)

Comment: @JamesC. One last quick question if I may, how would I use this as a parameter in a workflow, or is that better as another question\thread..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quotes so the variable can be expanded (see [about_quoting_rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules)), then add `*` to either end (or both) you want to wildcard:

```
{$_.ResourceGroupName -like "*$MyVar*"}
```